# AngularJS ng-model filling out all my inputs in a ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to get the input value of my input HTML in an ng-repeat. but when I write in the HTML side the first input, it will fill out all the other inputs. How can I avoid this and dissociate all the inputs? see below my HTML part:

```html
  
  <tr ng-repeat="item in data.list track by item.sys_id">
        <td ng-repeat="field in ::data.fields">{{::item[field].display_value}}</td>
        
            <td>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="c.data.comment">
            </td>
  
  </tr>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: can you add the structure of `data` aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define input as array and use different index for different inputs as ng-model, like this -

```
c.data.comment = ["input_0","input_1","" ...]
```

And use above based on index -

```
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="c.data.comment[$index]">
</td>
```

PS: please verify the syntax, this is how more or less you can handle this.

Comment: Thank you for your return Saurav, My c.data.comment is in a ng-repeat, that mean I will have create a bunch of input in the list, is not existing other solutions to solve this kind of situation ? 

By the way, where do you define the c.data.comment = ["input_0","input_1","" ...] ?

Comment: You solution is working, but I have only the index in the list and not the its value, how could I handle this to get the list of value ?

Comment: please share the current code snippet which seems to be working for you, that will give better context